# nodejs - Set-Cookie present in response but missing in browser

Tags: javascript, express, header, passport.js

I'm working with express.js and passport.js as my backened with axios and vue.js as my frontend.

**I can see my set-cookie but the cookie is not present in my browser.** Pictures linked below.

[Response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lR9gM.png)
[Request headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7xqH.png)

This cookie is used to authenticate my user using passport.js.

The following is the code for my express.js.

```js
var app = express();
app.use(cors({
  origin: "http://localhost:8080",
  credentials: true
}));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({
  secret: 'p@ssw0rd'
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

The method below will be called through vue.js methods.

```js
const url = "http://localhost:3000/";

let axiosConfig = {
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000/',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'
  }
}

class user {
  static login(username, password) {
    return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.post(
          `${url}login`, {
            username,
            password
          },
          axiosConfig
        );
        resolve(res.data);
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  }
```

Backend is run at localhost:3000 and frontend is run at localhost:8080

Inspecting cookies.
[No data presented for selected host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhmiZ.png)

Comment: Please check the domain on which the cookie is set ? Also in chrome browser, can you inspect and see in Application tabs the cookies are visible under localhost.

Comment: Hi, I've checked in my browser for my cookies but there are no data present for selected host on localhost:8080(frontend). I've added a picture in my post. How can I check the domain on which the cookie is set? I assume my cookie is set in my backened and did not reach the front. If so how to I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question and the solution is really stupid, nothing code related.
Since I am working on expressjs and a friend works on vuejs, he added two of the same folder that contains the axios methods. I changed the part which is not referenced.

The code I posted in my question works.